# List.js is returning wrong results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, listjs

I'm using List.js for the first time. I really liked it, and in the moment I am using it together with rails 4.2 to create a *Pokémon* team creator tool.
I am also using jQuery 1.11.3 as the JavaScript library for rails.

I have this right now:

[image: Pokémons list]

It's coded like this:

```
<script>
  var options = {
    valueNames: ['name']
  };
var userList = new List('pokemons', options);
</script>


<div id="pokemons">
  <input class="search form-control" placeholder="Search" />  
  <ul class="list" style="list-style: none; padding:0; margin:0;">
    <% PokemonDefault.where(forme: nil).each do |pokemon| %>
      <li>
        <div class="name">
          <%=image_tag 'miniaturePokemon/'+pokemon.code+'.png' %>
            <%=pokemon.name %>
        </div>
      </li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It gets all *pokémon* from *PokemonDefaults* table, and shows their image and name.

However, List.js is acting weird when I type stuff like 'baa':

[image: Weird behaviour of List.js]

As you can see, any of this *pokémon* has "baa" in their name.
What is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that `List` is getting confused because you have an `img` tag in your div. Try rendering your html like:

```
  <li>
    <%=image_tag 'miniaturePokemon/'+pokemon.code+'.png' %>
    <span class="name"><%=pokemon.name %></span>
  </li>
```

Comment: You were very accurate in your answer. I don't have any idea why `List` got "confused" with the `img` tag, but your answer solved my problem.

Comment: my guess it that it uses `innerHtml` to read the property value from the DOM., i.e. using jquery `$('.name').html()` as opposed to `$('.name').text()`, i'm too reliant on jQuery to know how to write it in vanilla js =P